# Convert my JSP Scriptlet code to EL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to print out info to the user using servlets and JSP. The ${sessionScope.student.getName()} is not working and I don't know why. Can someone please guide me?

```
<%
DevInfo stu = (DevInfo)getServletContext().getAttribute("student");
%>

<li><p>
            <b>Developers Name:</b>
             ${sessionScope.student.getName()}
        </p></li>
    <li><p>
```

DevInfo class:

```
public class DevInfo {

private String name;


public DevInfo (String name) {
    this.name = name;

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

}
```

The developer class which sets the attribute:`

```
  public class Developer implements ServletContextListener{


@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent e) {


    System.out.println("Destroyed!");



}

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent e) {
    ServletContext cntxt = e.getServletContext();

    String name = e.getServletContext().getInitParameter("dname");

    cntxt.log("gggg "+name);
    DevInfo student = new DevInfo(name);

    cntxt.setAttribute("student", student); 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing different *Scope* in *Expression language* :

```
Attribute "x" value in  page scope : ${x}
Attribute "x" in request scope : ${requestScope.x}
Attribute "x" in session scope : ${sessionScope.x}
```

Coming to your problem seems **Customer** is a bean class , So it's property can be accessed by  using below code snippet

```
${requestScope['control'].firstName}
```

With   `${x}`

Jsp container first checks in page scope for the attribute x .if it is available it prints attribute  value.  If it is not available then it will check in request scope followed by session and application scope.  It simply acts as

`pageContext.findAttribute(String name);`

method.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question, I was not clear enough. Can you please take a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.control.firstName}" />
```

Customer must be Java Bean.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

try this:

```
${student.getName()}
```

Assuming the property name is `name`:

```
${student.name}
```

Sample usage of jsp useBean:

```
<jsp:useBean id='test' class='package.Test' scope='page'/>
```

to invoke the method using EL

```
${test.getTest()}
```

Here, scope is by default `page`, can be `request`, `session`, etc

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question, I was not clear enough. Can you please take a look? Thanks.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Thank you. It worked fine. Just one question out of curiosity. If I had something called <%
 Test test = new Test();
%><%
 test.getTest();
%>
How would it be using EL. Would it be ${test.getTest()}?

Comment: @GarpLuffy, kindly accept my post, as it worked for you